# How to perform build and execute sh in sequence using maven

Tags: java, maven, automation, continuous-integration

I am using this section of `pom.xml` to execute a sh file which will trigger my regression test.

This section invokes the sh file.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>Regression_Test</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <executable>${basedir}/../../qascripting/Vdopia_Automation/exe/hudson_tc_execute.sh</executable>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When I execute command `mvn clean package` -- it just builds the code, doesn't trigger the sh and when I use command `mvn clean` verify --- it executes the `sh` but doesn't build the code. Now I want a command which should build the code first and then execute the sh.

whole pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.vdopia</groupId>
<artifactId>hudson</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
    <gson.version>2.2.4</gson.version>
    <guava.version>18.0</guava.version>
    <junit.version>4.10</junit.version>
    <netty.version>4.0.25.Final</netty.version>
    <wurfl.version>1.5.1</wurfl.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.7</slf4j.version>
    <redis.version>2.4.2</redis.version>
    <logger.version>0.3.1</logger.version>
    <org.apache.commons.pool.version>1.6</org.apache.commons.pool.version>
    <execplugin.version>1.3.2</execplugin.version>
    <commons.codec.version>1.9</commons.codec.version>
    <geoip.version>1.2.14</geoip.version>
    <org.json.version>20140107</org.json.version>
    <jacoco.version>0.7.2.201409121644</jacoco.version>
    <spymemcached.version>2.11.5</spymemcached.version>
    <aspectjweaver.version>1.8.0</aspectjweaver.version>
    <aspectjrt.version>1.8.0</aspectjrt.version>
    <apacheasynchttpclient.version>4.1</apacheasynchttpclient.version>
    <shadedjar.version>2.3</shadedjar.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!--plugin> <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId> <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
            <version>${jacoco.version}</version> <executions> <execution> <goals> <goal>prepare-agent</goal> 
            </goals> </execution> <execution> <id>report</id> <phase>prepare-package</phase> 
            <goals> <goal>report</goal> </goals> </execution> </executions> </plugin -->
        <!-- To download and link source code in eclipse -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${execplugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${shadedjar.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>com.vdopia.rtb.netty.Server.HudsonMain</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <!-- REGRESSION TEST -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>Regression_Test</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <!-- <phase>generate-test-sources</phase> -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <executable>${basedir}/../../qascripting/Vdopia_Automation/exe/hudson_tc_execute.sh</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- END -->

    </plugins>
</build>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>code-coverage</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>report</id>
                            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>report</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<modules>
    <module>utils</module>
    <module>rtb</module>
    <module>adResponse</module>
    <module>DAL</module>
    <module>cache</module>
    <module>redis</module>
    <module>extRequestProcessor</module>
    <module>netty</module>
    <module>ResponseGenerator</module>
    <module>RequestHandler</module>
    <module>Filter</module>
    <module>fluentData</module>
    <module>vast</module>
    <module>externalcache</module>
    <module>templates</module>
    <module>statistics</module>
</modules>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>${gson.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: If you execute `mvn verify` it is actually executing `package` phase too.

Comment: well if I execute mvn verify the maven doesn't build the code it just starts executing the Regression_Test. I wanted like maven should build first and then execute Regression_Test.

Comment: If you call a specific build phase, every phase prior to that phase is also executed. https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html So, package is actually being executed

Comment: Without the full pom it's not possible to answer your questions, cause as already mentioned if you do `mvn verify` all phases regarding compilation, testing etc. have run...

Comment: @khmarbaise: I am pasting the whole pom.xml here:

Comment: @Fran Montero: Even if I use mvn deploy or mvn verify, maven doesn't execute the unit tests, I am not sure why? Any help ...

Comment: What you have pasted is a multi-module parent pom.   Are the tests that you are referring in all the modules or some of them?  Also, a good practice is to use `pluginManagement` in parent pom and configure them in modules as appropriate

Answer (score 0):

The maven lifecycle controls the order. So you're doing fine by putting your sh command into the verify phase. Remember that if you get a failure in an earlier phase, then maven stops rather than moving forward to the next phase. Here's the order the phases execute in:
https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.3/maven-core/lifecycles.html

I put together a minimal pom and it works.
Here's my pom

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.simuquest.qp</groupId>
<artifactId>example1</artifactId>
<version>1.0.13333</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>


<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>Regression_Test</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <executable>java</executable>
                <workingDirectory>${basedir}\target</workingDirectory>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>-cp</argument>
                    <argument>${basedir}\target\example1-1.0.13333.jar</argument>
                    <argument>example1.NewMain</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and here's the output when I do "mvn install"

```
    Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0


--- maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2:jar (default-jar) @ example1 ---
Building jar: C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\NetBeansProjects\example1\target\example1-1.0.13333.jar

--- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (Regression_Test) @ example1 ---
hello

--- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @ example1 ---
Installing C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\NetBeansProjects\example1\target\example1-1.0.13333.jar to C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\com\simuquest\qp\example1\1.0.13333\example1-1.0.13333.jar
Installing C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\NetBeansProjects\example1\pom.xml to C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\com\simuquest\qp\example1\1.0.13333\example1-1.0.13333.pom
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So you can now compare working and not-working pom files. You can do a binary search to find out what parts of your pom are causing you grief. Why don't you start by dropping just about all those plugins. Remember that you only need to build without error in order to get through the phases and reach the verify phase.

Comment: to be precise, my problem is I can't build the developer code and execute my Regression_Test using the above pom.xml. If I use mvn package it just builds the developer code, If I use mvn verify then only Regression_Test is executed. I am not able to find the process/command which can build the developer code and then run the Regression_Test using above pom.xml.